# Access freezes when I try to connect with SQL Express

Tags: ms-access, odbc, sql-server-express

I have an Access formulary connected to an SQL Server Express using ODBC. The connection works in the service computer. I can add and modify data.
When I try to use this Access in a client computer, it freezes in the Access screen, and it loads after a few minutes. I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve question! Most likely this is caused by different ODBC drivers!

Comment: I revised my drivers and they're okay, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It not clear as to why Access would take so long to load. You do seem to suggest that it "eventually" does start to work, or is it that client stations don't work at all? (this is not 100% clear here).

It is assumed:
You install and have the front end part on each work station. 
That your client workstations are on the same office network. (if VPN's and other types of network connections are involved, then you are leaving out HUGE details here).

So, the copy of your front end (the application) of course is placed on each workstation.

If the workstations can "eventually" connect, then at least you know your network connection and drivers are ok. So, the next step would be to determine why the connection is so slow.  Or is it that each workstation does not work at all?

Comment: Yes, it eventually loads after a few minutes. I have a SQL express in the pc server, my Access formulary is connected to him with ODBC driver and I login with a SQL user and password. In the server it works perfect, but when I try to connect with this Access in a client and connect to the server, it freezes as I say.